# Unknown column 'ename' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql

I don't understand how to fix this. PhpMyAdmin cannot find columns. I even gave each query a name but it doesn't work.

```
SELECT ename, 
       deptno FROM ( SELECT sal 
                     FROM emp T
                   ) as E 
WHERE deptno = 10;
```

Comment: Can you please also add the tables?

Comment: Your main query uses a derived table (subquery in `FROM`) which selects only a `sal` column, that's why it says it can't find columns.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT sal FROM emp T`, return a table with only "sal" column. You select column ename and deptno from a table have only sal column is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

you have not a column named  ename in the subquery that you are use as table

could be you don't need the subquery

```
SELECT ename, deptno 
FROM emp WHERE deptno = 10;
```

or if you really need  the subquery then this must contain the column you are looking for

```
SELECT ename, deptno 
FROM (SELECT ename, deptno, sal FROM emp T) as E WHERE T.deptno = 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sql is wrong, you are trying to select `ename` and `deptno` columns from table `E`. `E` alias from `(SELECT sal FROM emp T)`, so it has the only one field named sal.